# PHPExcel print in column and cell

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am new to PHPexcel, trying to fetch data from my database and print the id and title values in it's own columns but right now it's just printing it like this, I want each value to be in each cell:

This is how the excel looks:

[image]

Code:

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="nih_bw";
$sqlsrv="localhost";
date_default_timezone_set('US/Central');
$currenttime=date("m-d-Y");

require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties();

function num2alpha($n)
{
    for($r = ""; $n >= 0; $n = intval($n / 26) - 1)
        $r = chr($n%26 + 0x41) . $r;
    return $r;
}

$viewinv = mysql_connect($sqlsrv,$username,$password);
if (!$viewinv) { die('Could not connect to SQL server. Contact administrator.'); }
mysql_select_db($database, $viewinv) or die('Could not connect to database. Contact administrator.');
$query = "select id, title from measurements;";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('CYImport'.$currenttime.'');

$rowNumber = 1;
$headings = array('id','Title');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(array($headings),NULL,'A'.$rowNumber);
$rowNumber++;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $col = '0';
   foreach($row as $cell) {

     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(num2alpha($col).$rowNumber,$cell);
      $col++;
   }
   $rowNumber++;
}


   $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_CSV($objPHPExcel);

$objWriter->setDelimiter("\t");
$objWriter->setEnclosure('');
$objWriter->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter->save('blah '.$currenttime.'.csv');


   header('Content-type: text/csv');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="CY Import '.$currenttime.'"..csv"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

   $objWriter->save('php://output');
   exit();
}
echo 'Contact your Administrator. No data received from server.';

?>
```

Comment: Instead of your `num2alpha()`, consider using PHPExcel's built-in `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()` method

Comment: But why are you setting the delimiter for a CSV to `''`? and the enclosure to `''`..... this is the likely cause of your problem: if you have to change the delimiter, at least change it to a valid character like a `"\t"` that will still be recognised when the generated file is loaded into MS Excel

Comment: Changed it to "\t", see edit. This is how it looks. In one cell. I want it to put id in one column and title in another. https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9fk125v1z34gzs/howitlooks.png

Comment: I really can't understand what your reader is doing: you're generating a perfectly valid CSV file (if you open it in a text editor, you can see for yourself), but Excel is simply failing to read it correctly.... as you're using PHPExcel, have you tried using the Excel5 or Excel2007 Writers instead of CSV?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that $col has to be a character if you use setCellValue - to use a number you can use setCellValueByColumnAndRow instead, eg:-

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col,$rowNumber,$cell);
```

Alternatively you can convert $col into a character by using the function below:-

```
function num2alpha($n)
{
    for($r = ""; $n >= 0; $n = intval($n / 26) - 1)
        $r = chr($n%26 + 0x41) . $r;
    return $r;
}
```

and then call it as before:-

```
$col = 0;
foreach($row as $cell) {
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(num2alpha($col).$rowNumber,$cell);
  $col++;
}
$rowNumber++;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But now I am not getting the id's out in the excel. Only the titles.

Comment: Are you still setting $col = 'A' before the loop ?  If so then set it to 0

Comment: I have updated my code up, change it to 0. But I want to print the id values in it's own column and the title values in it's own. On the left side how it looks now and the right side show how I want it to look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mi7becx85610rln/howIwant.png

Comment: You are calling $objWriter->setDelimiter(''); but you are outputting to CSV.  A CSV needs a delimiter or else the fields will run together, so just delete this line.

Comment: I sat it to (,) but that didn't make the id and title to come in each column. Can you please help me solve that ?

Comment: I just ran your code, and it worked fine for me - displayed in Excel in separate cells.  Can you paste up the contents of the CSV file it generated?

Comment: Here is the link of the generated content, as you can see the id and title come in one cell: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4q6148sm7dgxy1/CY%20Import%2004-26-2014-.%20%2822%29.csv

Comment: That CSV file opens fine for me in Excel, in different cells

Comment: Could you please give me the link of you excel generated ?

Comment: It's running on my local server so I can't send a link, but if I open the very same file you just sent me in Excel, it works.